# Insert function pointer into QMap (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, function-pointers, qmap

I am creating sort of a router for REST API in Qt and I am facing problem with inserting the function pointer into the QMap.

I have class `IModule` from which the other modules are derivated.
Important lines of `IModule.h` are

```
typedef QByteArray* (*IBusAction)(IBus * , ProxyRequest *);

class IModule : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT

  protected:
    QMap<QString , IBusAction > *m_actions;
```

Then I have `UserModule` which is derived from `IModule` and in `.cpp` file I have these lines:

```
QByteArray* UserModule::create(IBus *bus, ProxyRequest *req)
{
}

QByteArray* UserModule::show( IBus *bus, ProxyRequest *req)
{
}


UserModule::UserModule(QObject *parent) :
IModule(parent)
{

    // register functions
    m_actions->insert("show", &UserModule::show);
    m_actions->insert("create", UserModule::create);

}
```

So I tried two options how to put the function in QMap with referencing sign also without it, but both are not working. I am getting error: `no matching function for call to 'QMap<QString, QByteArray* (*)(IBus*, ProxyRequest*)>::insert(const char [5], QByteArray* (UserModule::*)(IBus*, ProxyRequest*))'`

I have spent several hours with this problem, tried many different things how to solve it but there was no success.

So I will be very glad for any piece of advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `IBusAction` is a pointer-to-function type. This is not compatible with pointer-to-member function.

When you call a member function (like your `UserModule::create` function), it needs an extra ("invisible") parameter: the instance the function gets called on (the `this` pointer).

You have essentially three options:

- Change `IBusAction` to be a pointer-to-member-function-of-`UserModule`. You're restricted to that class's functions with this though.

  ```
  typedef QByteArray* (UserModule::*IBusAction)(IBus * , ProxyRequest *);
  ```
- Make the functions `static` (this changes the semantics of your code)
- Use free-standing functions (top-level, not members of a class) instead of member functions.

Comment: As the UserModule is derivated from IModule which also defines functions show and create but they are virtual, I have tried    typedef QByteArray* (IModule::*IBusAction)(IBus * , ProxyRequest *);  But it was not working and I don't know why.

Comment: sry i edited my above comment  because in the middle of writing I accidentally pressed enter

Comment: Won't work that way either, a pointer to a member function of the derived class is not compatible with a pointer to member of the base. (You can't call a derived function on a base object; the other way around works though.)

Comment: Ok these are the bad news, but thank you very much for help :))

Answer (score 0):

Pointers to member functions in C++ is generally more hassle than it is worth. Sane alternative is to have class instead of method, and keep pointer to instance instead of method.

Qt specific alternative is to use invokable methods of QObject based class, which you can call by string name, using QObject::invokeMethod, side-stepping many type problems.