# Function pointer from QMap

Tags: c++, qt, function-pointers, qmap

I'm trying to implement factory method pattern in my QT project following this example: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363338/Factory-Pattern-in-Cplusplus

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

class IAnimal
{
public:
    virtual int GetNumberOfLegs() const = 0;
    virtual void Speak() = 0;
    virtual void Free() = 0;
};
typedef IAnimal* (__stdcall *CreateAnimalFn)(void);

// IAnimal implementations
class Cat : public IAnimal
{
public:
    int GetNumberOfLegs() const { return 4; }
    void Speak() { qDebug() << "Meow" << endl; }
    void Free() { delete this; }

    static IAnimal * __stdcall Create() { return new Cat(); }
};

class Dog : public IAnimal
{
public:
    int GetNumberOfLegs() const { return 4; }
    void Speak() { qDebug() << "Woof" << endl; }
    void Free() { delete this; }

    static IAnimal * __stdcall Create() { return new Dog(); }
};
```

Factory class:

```
// Factory for creating instances of IAnimal
class AnimalFactory
{
private:
    AnimalFactory();
    AnimalFactory(const AnimalFactory &) { }
    AnimalFactory &operator=(const AnimalFactory &) { return *this; }

    typedef QMap<QString,CreateAnimalFn> FactoryMap;
    FactoryMap m_FactoryMap;
public:
    ~AnimalFactory() { m_FactoryMap.clear(); }

    static AnimalFactory *Get()
    {
        static AnimalFactory instance;
        return &instance;
    }

    void Register(const QString &animalName, CreateAnimalFn pfnCreate);
    IAnimal *CreateAnimal(const QString &animalName);
};

AnimalFactory::AnimalFactory()
{
    Register("Cat", &Cat::Create);
    Register("Dog", &Dog::Create);
}

void AnimalFactory::Register(const QString &animalName, CreateAnimalFn pfnCreate)
{
    m_FactoryMap[animalName] = pfnCreate;
}

IAnimal *AnimalFactory::CreateAnimal(const QString &animalName)
{
    FactoryMap::iterator it = m_FactoryMap.find(animalName);
    if( it != m_FactoryMap.end() )
    return it.value();
    return NULL;
}
```

However I am encountering such an error:

```
cannot convert 'IAnimal* (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *)()' to 'IAnimal*' in return
         return it.value();
```

Only existing anwser ([Insert function pointer into QMap (Qt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330806/insert-function-pointer-into-qmap-qt)) suggests making Create() functions static which doesn't seem to help.

I will be very grateful for any piece of advice.

Comment: `return it.value()();` Once you obtained the function pointer with `it.value()`, you need to actually call the function.

Comment: Ahhh so simple. Anyway many thanks to you, it worked!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik consider to make an actual answer, this would help future reader to have an accepted answer to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

That's a little bit complicated. You're writing C++, so you shouldn't be copying Java. C++ is way more expressive here.

1. You won't need the explicit `Create`/`Free` methods - the compiler can generate them for you, automatically.
2. You definitely need a virtual destructor, otherwise the interface will be useless. Any class you intend to derive from must have a virtual destructor, with very few specialized exceptions from this rule.
3. All implementations of virtual methods should be declared `override`, including the destructor, but not `virtual` as that'd violate DRY.
4. The classes can carry their names, so that the factory can register them just by knowing their types. This is an optional behavior of the factory.

```
#include <QtCore>

class IAnimal {
public:
    virtual int GetNumberOfLegs() const = 0;
    virtual QString Speaks() = 0;
    virtual ~IAnimal() {}
};

class Cat : public IAnimal {
public:
    int GetNumberOfLegs() const override { return 4; }
    QString Speaks() override { return QStringLiteral("Meow"); }
    static auto className() { return "Cat"; }
};

class Dog : public IAnimal {
public:
    int GetNumberOfLegs() const override { return 4; }
    QString Speaks() override { return QStringLiteral("Woof"); }
    static auto className() { return "Dog"; }
};
```

Now we can have a generic factory. Note that all sane C++ container types manage their data. You don't need to explicitly clear them on destruction. We're leveraging C++11. The `Register` method will only accept types that derive from `Interface`, and that method automatically generates a construction function using the lambda expression.

The lifetime of the instance should be controlled explicitly by instantiating it in `main()`.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeindex>
#include <map>

template <class Interface> class Factory {
  template <class C, class T = void> struct enable_if_I :
    std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Interface, C>::value, T> {};
  using create_fn = Interface* (*)();
  std::map<QByteArray, create_fn, std::less<>> m_creators;
  std::map<std::type_index, QByteArray> m_names;
  static Factory *&instance_ref() { // assume no inline static yet
    static Factory *m_instance;
    return m_instance;
  }
  Factory(const Factory &) = delete;
  Factory &operator=(const Factory &) = delete;
public:
  Factory() {
    Q_ASSERT(!instance());
    instance_ref() = this;
  }
  virtual ~Factory() { instance_ref() = {}; }
```

In general, registration requires the type and name of the derived class. This presupposes nothing about whether the class has a `className()` member. The factory stores both the factory function and the name. This allows name look up without having `className` as a virtual method of the interface.

```
  template <class T> typename enable_if_I<T>::type Register(const QByteArray &name) {
    m_creators[name] = +[]()->Interface* { return new T(); };
    m_names[{typeid(T)}] = name;
  }
```

When class names are known, we can leverage them to register one or more classes, given just their types.

```
  template <class T1> typename enable_if_I<T1>::type Register() {
    this->Register<T1>(T1::className());
  }
  template <class T1, class T2, class...T> typename enable_if_I<T1>::type Register() {
    this->Register<T1>(T1::className());
    this->Register<T2, T...>();
  }
```

The instance creation methods are optimized not to copy the name given, no matter the format. This is why we use the `std::map<K, V, std::less<>>` map with a transparent comparator. `QByteArray` provides `operator<` that takes various types on the right-hand side, and to exploit this, the type of the key (here: name) must reach the comparator.

```
  template <typename T> static Interface *CreateA(T &&t) {
      return instance() ? instance()->Create(std::forward<T>(t)) : nullptr;
  }
  Interface *Create(QLatin1String name) const { return Create(name.data()); }
  template <typename T> Interface *Create(T &&name) const;
  static const QByteArray &NameOfA(const Interface * obj);
  const QByteArray &NameOf(const Interface *) const;
  static Factory *instance() { return instance_ref(); }
};

template <class Interface>
template <typename T> Interface *Factory<Interface>::Create(T &&name) const {
  auto it = m_creators.find(name);
  return (it != m_creators.end()) ? it->second() : nullptr;
}
namespace detail { 
const QByteArray & null() { static const QByteArray n; return n; }
}
template <class Interface>
const QByteArray &Factory<Interface>::NameOfA(const Interface *obj) {
  return instance() ? instance()->NameOf(obj) : detail::null();
}
template <class Interface>
const QByteArray &Factory<Interface>::NameOf(const Interface *obj) const {
  auto it = m_names.find(typeid(*obj));
  return (it != m_names.end()) ? it->second : detail::null();
}
```

The generic factory takes the interface and concrete types and registers them all in the constructor. This makes building the factories simple.

```
template <class Interface, class ...Types>
class GenericFactory : public Factory<Interface> {
public:
  GenericFactory() {
    this->template Register<Types...>();
  }
};

using AnimalFactory = GenericFactory<IAnimal, Cat, Dog>;
```

Example of use, with asserts to indicate desired behavior. Note that to destroy the objects, one merely has to `delete` their instance. The compiler will generate the calls.

```
int main() {
  Q_ASSERT(!AnimalFactory::instance());
  {
    AnimalFactory animals;
    Q_ASSERT(AnimalFactory::instance());
    auto *dog1 = AnimalFactory::CreateA("Dog");
    Q_ASSERT(dynamic_cast<Dog*>(dog1));
    Q_ASSERT(AnimalFactory::NameOfA(dog1) == Dog::className());
    Q_ASSERT(dog1->Speaks() == QStringLiteral("Woof"));
    auto *dog2 = AnimalFactory::CreateA(QLatin1String("Dog"));
    Q_ASSERT(dynamic_cast<Dog*>(dog2));
    auto *cat = AnimalFactory::CreateA("Cat");
    Q_ASSERT(dynamic_cast<Cat*>(cat));
    Q_ASSERT(cat->Speaks() == QStringLiteral("Meow"));
    Q_ASSERT(AnimalFactory::NameOfA(cat) == Cat::className());
    delete cat;
    delete dog2;
    delete dog1;
  }
  Q_ASSERT(!AnimalFactory::instance());
}
```

Comment: I forgot that the free-standing function return types don't support covariance. Fixed.